# .NET MVC Websites - shared folders between websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a production website that sits on two servers that used local label files to drive their page labels (request going round robin between the two).

Users need the ability to upload new labels files, but once uploaded on one I need it also updated on the second website - this needs to be immediate. I was trying to use a shared folder on one of the servers, but even if I give it everyone full access i get the error  `"Exception message: Unable to find label folder at \\MACHINENAME\LabelFiles"` when reading from the other server, I've also tried giving full permissions to `"IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool"`, but get the same issue.

I'm using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Question-

Is there a way to share a folder between the two sites?

Is there a better alternative solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the websites should have a virtual folder pointing to the same physical folder, where the users can upload files.
Make sure also that the Anonymous access is disabled

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to map the folder as a drive on each of the production machines, it should then be as simple as refereing to that particular drive letter.

This can be done by navigating to the folder in windows explorer, then clicking Map Network Drive.

I cannot guarantee this will work, buut it might be worth a go.

Answer (score 0):

The IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool user is a special account that is only local to the machine where it is being used.  You cannot access network file shares with that account.  You will either need to use the 'Network Service' account or a domain account as the app pool user.

Also, since you are load balancing this site between two servers, you might want to consider using some type of SAN or NAS storage that is shared between the two servers.  Otherwise, you will need to come up with some kind of process to synchronize the file share on both servers.